# python selenium webdriver actions chains key enter is not working on some machine

Tags: python, selenium

I need to automate using webdriver to send keys followed by an enter. but the enter is not getting triggered. and this happens only on some machine. i tried increasing delays between the sendkeys and enter. both machines failing and passing 1 have same python packages/versions.

send_keys(Keys.ENTER) does not work on some machines.

```
ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath")
ele.send_keys("test")
time.sleep(2)
ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
```

i even tried ele.send_key(Keys.ENTER) and ele.send_key("\n"). 
but noting is working.  tried increasing delays as well. but no luck

Comment: Could you try this?
`ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(ele).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()`

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like pykeyboard for key-related issues like this. It's a useful backup at the very least.

The pykeyboard package allows you to automate keystrokes and hotkeys for various tasks. I often use it when Selenium gives me trouble with finding the appropriate elements or just not letting me send_keys at all.

I wrote-up an example this morning on the link here if you're interested:

[How to implement key combinations (including modifier keys) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34324025/how-to-implement-key-combinations-including-modifier-keys-in-python/36161835)

Good Luck.